# checking if child exists

Tags: actionscript-3

Hello i have a function as following:

```
private function seatClickHandler(e:MouseEvent):void{

            var check:Check = new Check();
            if(e.target.contains(check)){
                e.target.removeChild(seat);
            }else{
                e.target.addChild(check);
            }
        }
```

basicly i want to check if e.target contains a child called check. If it does i want e.target to remove the child, else i want to add the child. But the method i tried doesnt seem to work although i think this is the way to go. Any suggestions?

Comment: Did you manage to get everything working?

Comment: yes i did, sorry, lost sight of it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you declare your Check object, Actionscript creates a reference code for that specific object.

So the first time your code is run, your `Check` object could be given a reference of `@c0ecc29`. Your `if` statement checks to see if `@c0ecc29` is a child component of `target`. It won't be, so the `Check` object with reference `@c0ecc29` is added to `target`.

The second time the `clickHandler` is called, a new instance of the `Check` object is created which will have a *new* reference id. Your target has the original Check object with the `@c0ecc29` reference so it won't get removed.

The correct way to get this working depends on what target is (DataGrid, Group, etc.).

**EDIT:**
Based on your comments, I would try something like this. It checks to see if the `Check` object is a child of `target` and adds it if needed. Then when the `Check` object is clicked, it will toggle its visibility.

```
public var check:Check = new Check();

private function seatClickHandler(e:MouseEvent):void
{
  if(!e.target.contains(check))
  {
    check.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, check_handleClick);
    e.target.addChild(check);
  }
}

protected function check_handleClick(event:MouseEvent):void
{
  check.visible = !check.visible;
}
```

If you need to actually remove the `Check` object from `target` instead of just changing its visibility, you could try this:

```
public var check:Check = new Check();

private function seatClickHandler(e:MouseEvent):void
{
  if(!e.target.contains(check))
  {
    e.target.addChild(check);
  }
  else
  {
    e.target.removeChild(check);
  }
}
```

Comment: Is the sprite in a repeater or data group? Is it part of a larger component? Are you just trying to show/hide the "Check" object?

Comment: I'm just trying to hide/show the object, its not in a repeater or anything

Comment: I've updated my answer based on your comments. I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

If the child is named `'check'` then you should be able to use `getChildByName()`. See [flash.display.DisplayObject.name](http://www.adobe.com/livedocs/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/display/DisplayObject.html#name)

If you happen to have the child in memory, you can use `getChildIndex()`

Answer (score 0):

check is a new object in the scope of that function, so it will not be a child of the event target.

What you want to do is declare check as a global variable (And also cast target as DisplayObjectContainer).

e.g.

```
private function seatClickHandler(e:MouseEvent):void{
                if((e.target as DisplayObjectContainer).contains(check)){
                    (e.target as DisplayObjectContainer).removeChild(seat);
                }else{
                    (e.target as DisplayObjectContainer).addChild(check);
                }
    }
```

However I'm not sure if this is exactly what you want to do (There can only be one check). A better approach would be to have a function (maybe toggleCheck) on the target, and have that display object responsible for rendering the check (And removing it)

Answer (score 0):

This worked perfectly fine for me in my situation:

```
if(possibleChild.parent == holder)
    holder.removeChild(possibleChild)
```

It may or may not be exactly what you're looking for.